# CSS Rotate Text, while having container always be in bottom:0, left:0 position

Tags: css

I am trying to accomplish the following with CSS:
 [image]

I have a **[code pen started here](http://codepen.io/jharding/pen/MYgqYp)**

I can easily rotate the text as I would like with the following CSS:

```
.Rotate {
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

However, the text ends up as shown below
[image]

I understand why it's happening, but unsure how to globally solve it. It is using the bottom left corner before you rotate it. I can individually with each widget place a fixed height/width on the `.title` But if at all possible. I would like to avoid that.

Can anyone provide a solution that would allow the 'rotated' text to always be located at `bottom:0, left:0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the origin to bottom left, and then apply a translation to the element, prior to the rotation

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
-webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
transform-origin: bottom left;
```

The translation makes the top left corner be where you want it, so to speak.

It's not easy to explain how it works... just try it

Comment: holy smokes, you're a wizard

Comment: Wow. That's really impressive, I didn't think this would be doable with just CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would just make the elements a little more intricate but singular with :before & :after. Then I'd position the text within a position absolute.

```
.widget {
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #81a6d5;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #084ca1;
}

.widget::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 35px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

.widget .title {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

I made this pen to show the idea, it would clean up the coding a little bit also.

http://codepen.io/brycesnyder/pen/PwYdJq

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to think of a way to universally be able to do this with CSS without positioning each one individually, but with JS it was pretty easy. If you can use JS intead, this code should take care of it on its own, without changing any of your current HTML or CSS.

```
$(function(){
    $('.rotate').each(function(){

        var thisTitle = $(this);
        var w = thisTitle.outerWidth();
        var h = thisTitle.outerHeight();

        var newLeft = Math.abs((w - h) / 2) * -1;
        var newBottom = Math.abs((w - h) / 2);

        thisTitle.css('left', newLeft);
        thisTitle.css('bottom', newBottom);

    });

});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/supah_frank/pen/yyBxzo

Comment: Creative, can't decide if I want to use .js or not

Comment: It really depends on how you want to do it. If the tags are going to be a constant height and width, you can get away with doing it just through css, but if that if the sizes are going to vary and you don't want to do each tag individually, you will need to us js.

The longer side will always need to be offset half the size of the negative of longer side minus the shorter side and the shorter side will need to have half the longer side minus the shorter side added to it. If the sizes are always the same, you can just do the math your self, but css doesn't have access to those values.

Comment: for now these 2 'widgets' are the only two planned, but I do like the solution

Comment: In that case, if it were me and you have no other use for js and JQuery, I would probably just do the math and hard code them. I think a lot of people will disagree, but for me, having to hard code two variables is better than having to worry about a fallback for people who have JS turned off. Maybe save this code commented out or something, just in case the amount of tags grows in the future.